# how to upload file from mobile using phonegap ? Is there any phonegap plugin required to upload file?

Tags: cordova, mobile, file-upload, phonegap

We are trying to upload files from a phonegap mobile app to a web server
Using default file upload option in existing web application

We tried just build the apk using phone gap

Our question is how upload file from mobile  using phonegap? Is there any phonegap plugin required to upload file ?

Answer (score 0):

yes. To upload or to download a file from webserver you need to use **file transfer plugin**. Add the following plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Sample code to upload a file is

```
var win = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}

var fail = function (error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
}

var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
options.mimeType = "text/plain";

var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Comment: actually i want  <html:file property="filename" value="Upload" ></html:file> this code to work in phone gap

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-chooser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

After adding the above plugins  html input file can be works fine
no change required in existing web application code

Answer (score 0):

Add these to project:

**in  `app/res/xml/config.xml :`**

```
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />
```

**in  `app/AndroidManifest.xml`**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```